# Coinbase payment iframe switching api versions

Tags: coinbase-api

I am setting up my site to use the Coinbase iframe for accepting payments.

I am testing using the sandbox.

Sometimes when I make a payment the callback to my server takes the form:

```
{
  "order": {
    "id": "YDWALXJW",
    "uuid": "2a6de442-be7b-5517-9b49-f00908460115",
    "resource_path": "/v2/orders/2a6de442-be7b-5517-9b49-f00908460115",
    "metadata": null,
    "created_at": "2015-12-06T16:58:02-08:00",
    "status": "completed",
    ...
```

and other times it looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "f08d1f11-27f9-5be2-87fd-e086d1b67cab",
  "type": "wallet:orders:paid",
  "data": {
    "resource": {
      "id": "309a20df-a8e6-532d-9a2b-3ce5ea754d6d",
      "code": "52N6TG58",
      "type": "order",
      ...
```

I realize this is probably just api v1 vs v2, but I don't understand why it seems to be randomly switching back and forth. Any ideas of how to make it just use v2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you've entered the same URL as both a Notifications (v2) and Callback (v1) URL.

[image]

This is easy to do, given that there are 3 different places in the UI where you can provide either or both the callback/notifications URL.

1. [Merchant Settings Page](https://www.coinbase.com/merchant_settings)
2. [Your API Key's Edit form](https://www.coinbase.com/settings/api)
3. [The Merchant Tools Generator](https://www.coinbase.com/merchant_tools?link_type=hosted)

You'll receive a POST message for each place you've entered this URL. (I was able to get 5 unique POSTs in my testing!)

The right place to include the URL depends on your situation:

- If you just want [merchant notifications](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/merchants/notifications) (paid orders, mispaid orders and payouts), put it in the Merchant settings page.
- If you are building an app with functionality beyond merchant tools, and want a broader set of [wallet notifications](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/merchants/notifications), put it in your API Key's Edit form.

For Merchants I would generally not recommend entering the URL for a button generated via option 3. Based on the title of your question, I'm guessing this is your situation.

You won't be able to view or edit this setting in the future. If you're re-using a static button that you've previously generated, and think that you've included a URL there which you'd like removed, you'll need to replace the button by generating a new one.

I hope that helps!